# Transfer data from one table to another along with other values (SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I want to insert data from several tables into one table along with some default values.

Suppose I have 3 tables:

```
**table1**(col1, col2, col3, col4)
**table2**(col5, col6)
**table3**(col7)
```

I want to

```
insert in table1.col1 -> table2.col5, 
table1.col2 -> table2.col6,

table1.col3 -> table3.col7,

table1.col4 -> 'default_value' for some WHERE condition.
```

I tried using `INSERT INTO...SELECT FROM` but that allows me to enter values only when all the values for `**table1**` are taken from other tables and not for `**"default_value"**.`  I cannot use 2 different queries since all columns from `table1` have `NOT NULL` constraint on them.

Can anyone help me how to forward with this?

Comment: What does the query you wrote look like now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown what query you have tried which helps those people trying to help you to avoid suggesting something you have already tried.
However, despite not knowing what you HAVE tried this should work - it certainly does for me.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (col1, col2, col3, col4)
SELECT t2.first_name, t2.age, t3.salary, 'DEFAULT VALUE'
FROM   table2 t2
       INNER JOIN
       table3 t3
       ON t2.rec_id = t3.rec_id
```